# NuGet: Unknown option "-co" on push

Tags: .net, build, nuget

I am creating a nuget build for one of my projects. I already have a nuget package build for a similar project where everything works as expected. However, this new nuget build definition fails, and the error message I get is:

```
Error reported in the NuGet Process: Unknown option: '-co'
```

This is given on the following build step:

```
PushWithNuGet
  Push Arguments: push "MyLocation\MyPackage.nupkg" 
  29f90a50-debe-4a44-ad1a-f7a5dcc354c1 -co -s "http://myPackageServer/"
```

The exact same command is being called for the mentioned similar build, and there is works. So it doesn't seem to me like the command doesn't exist - even though I can't see it in the [nuget documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Push_Command).

So; why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a difference in nuget.exe-versions. The old build definition - which was working - did use nuget.exe version 1.8.30604.0. The newly added project had version 2.2.40207.9053. Apparently the option "-co" existed in this old version, but not in the new one. The solution obviously must be to remove the flag from the build definition and upgrade to use the latest nuget.exe.